# How do I use double and message chain in ruby rspec

Tags: ruby, rspec, mocking

I am working on Plain Ruby Project(Non Rails Environment). However, I am getting an error,

```
 #<Double "pr"> received unexpected message :client with (no args)
```

This error is returned from the double object with label pr.
Here's my rspec, I have configured the Sinatra as a fake github server and its returning a JSON response.
I have verifed the result and its returning a JSON response.

```
RSpec.describe Humdrum::DefaultVerifications::CodeReviewsSignedOff do
  describe '.Code Reviews Signed Off' do
    let(:org){
      'octocat'
    }
    let(:number){
      123
    }
    before do
      uri = URI('https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/hello-world/pulls/42/reviews')
      result=JSON.load(Net::HTTP.get(uri))
      github=double
      allow(github)
      .to receive_message_chain(:client,:pull_request_reviews)
      .with(:org,:number)
      .and_return (result)
    end
    it 'should check pull request review response' do
      object=Humdrum::DefaultVerifications::CodeReviewsSignedOff.new
      github=double("pr")
      expert(object.pull_request_reviews_response(github)). to eq(1)
    end
  end
  
end
```

As you can see in the function pull_request_reviews_response, I want to stub the github.client.pull_request_reviews, hence, in the rspec for this file,
I wrote allow, message chain and from there it returns json response.
That json response will be proccessed inside the same function and return a integer response

```
module Humdrum
  module DefaultVerifications
    class CodeReviewsSignedOff
      def pull_request_reviews_response(github)
        #Counting total number of user who have approved the pull request
        approveCount=0
      github.client.pull_request_reviews("#{github.organization}/#{github.repository}", github.number).each do |review|
          username = review[:user][:login]
          state    = review[:state]
          if state == "APPROVED" and !@@approvedUser.include?(username)
            @@approvedUser.add(username)
            puts "Changes #{state} by #{username}"
            approveCount += 1
          end
        end
        return approveCount

      end
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

> What am I doing wrong?

You have defined `github` as a local variable, in two different places:

```
before
  # ...
  github = double # <----- HERE
  allow(github)
    .to receive_message_chain(:client, :pull_request_reviews)
    .with(:org, :number)
    .and_return(result)
end

it 'should check pull request review response' do
  # ...
  github = double("pr") # <-- AND ALSO HERE
  expert(object.pull_request_reviews_response(github)).to eq(1)
end
```

So the object you send to the method doesn't have any stubs. Hence the error message.

There are various ways you could choose to structure this test (for instance, we could talk about how using `double` is generally a bad idea, and so is using `receive_message_chain` !... I'd opt to at least use `instance_double`, or potentially even just pass a real object here.).

But as a minimal change, here's a way you could define the `github` variable once, and reference the same object in the `before` block and the spec itself:

```
let(:github) { double("pr") } # <---- !!!

before
  # ...
  allow(github)
    .to receive_message_chain(:client, :pull_request_reviews)
    .with(:org, :number)
    .and_return(result)
end

it 'should check pull request review response' do
  # ...
  expert(object.pull_request_reviews_response(github)).to eq(1)
end
```

Comment: Thank it works.
I am really sorry to trouble you again.
Now, there is one more error, :organization with (no args).
Do, I have to define organization variable 
Using let(:github.organization){"octokat") and same for number?

Comment: Oh... Yeah, that's because you `.to receive_message_chain(:client, :pull_request_reviews).with(:org, :number)` -- but why would `"#{github.organization}/#{github.repository}"` equal `:org`? And why would `github.number` equal `:number`?

Comment: So again, more stubs would be needed if you continue with this current testing style. Maybe something like: `allow(github).to receive(:organization).and_return('github_org')`, and so on.

Comment: Look at what methods the code is actually calling, and look at what you have mocked. There is currently no mock for `github.organization`, `github.repository` or `github.number`. So if you pass in a `double` without specifying what those method calls should return, the spec will fail.

Comment: You can also define these simple values in a hash, directly, instead of writing `allow(github).to receive(.....)` for each of them. See [the docs](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs/basics/test-doubles#a-hash-can-be-used-to-define-allowed-messages-and-return-values).

Comment: Yes, thank you very much.